# how to addfile to ipset in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, iptables, ipset

This is my ipset shell script file like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for IP in $(wget -O /var/geoiptest.txt http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{ad,ae,af}.zone)
do
# ban everything - block country
sudo ipset add geo /var/geoiptest.txt
done
```

i think last row have fault, how can i resolve that ?

Comment: what do you mean by last row have default ?

Comment: i resolve that it was mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iteration is wrong. the correct syntax would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo wget -O /var/geoiptest.txt http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/{ad,ae,af}.zone
while read ip; do
    sudo ipset add geo $ip
done < /var/geoiptest.txt
```